# What's the proper action for moderating answers using the wrong programming language?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, moderation

While reviewing first posts, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360183/call-non-static-method-from-static-method-c-sharp/13766527#13766527), which uses C++ code to attempt answering a C# question.

Clearly, this is not a correct answer, since the code won't compile in C#. However, it's also clearly a good faith attempt at answering the question. Aside: the upvotes came from review queue upvoting robots.

Other than downvoting, commenting, and posting here (all of which I've done), **in the general case for this sort of situation**, what action should be taken?

The posted code *might* be mungeable in to a C# answer without changing its spirit, but that would involve more substantive changes than I feel is appropriate for an edit.

I don't think "not an answer" flag is justified, since it is an answer, albeit a severely misguided one. Seems like a custom moderator attention flag would be appropriate, but I decided to ask here, to get more robust feedback than I would from the flag response.

Comment: Side issue: sometimes the author will tag a question with the language they are working in, but the question is in some sense language agnostic. I once [answered such a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/687731/2509) when I didn't know [language] using pseudo-code to make the point. Certainly it would have been silly to use some other language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *is* an answer, so flagging it as "not an answer" would be inappropriate.

The proper course of action is to downvote it<sup>1</sup> and, perhaps, leave a comment to alert the author to what's wrong with it. No Moderation is necessary.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'd suggest that posting an answer in the wrong programming language is the very definition of "not helpful".

Answer (score 8):

I'd downvote and comment, as you did. No other action is required, really.

*Usually* these answers are from someone who genuinely didn't realize it was the wrong programming language they used, or from someone new eager to provide *an* answer.

Answer (score 8):

As far as answers go, correctness is more important than effort.

Especially if the question is about language features, such as that, then yes, you should **downvote**, and **leave a comment**, and then the answer can either edit his answer to be more correct or he might choose to delete it considering that there are other answers.

It is a very common pattern for

- someone to post a partially-correct but not fully-correct answer,
- that answer gets downvoted,
- the answerer corrects his answer,
- and the downvoters recinds their downvote(and maybe even up-votes it).

Answer (score 6):

You should just downvote it and move on. 'Moderation' is not needed for every little transgression.